# twitter integration for login purpose

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I'm implementing twitter integration  to my application.

```
SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"screen_name"]];
```

but I'm getting response

```
{"errors":[{"code":50,"text message":"User not found."}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not familiar with SLRequest but I give you an alternative solution,

Use these pod lines

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'TwitterLogin'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'TwitterKit'
    pod 'TwitterCore'
```

Add these lines in your info.plist replace with your `APIKey`, `consumerkey`, `consumerSecret`

```
<key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>ffXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX14</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>KitInfo</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>consumerKey</key>
                    <string>KjXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXD</string>
                    <key>consumerSecret</key>
                    <string>3gXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXbd</string>
                </dict>
                <key>KitName</key>
                <string>Twitter</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Then call this code for login,

```
- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {

    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession * _Nullable session, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (session) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [session userID]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [session userName]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [session authToken]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [session authTokenSecret]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

}
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: my code every thing fine except i am getting nil  form twitterInfoRequest

Comment: check APIKey, consumerkey, consumerSecret

Comment: i have only consumer key and consumersecret
api key is needed "

Comment: No need of API key.

Comment: i want to change both  consumer key and secret

Comment: Yes you have to use your consumer key and secret key that provided for your app in your developer account.